# Logic app to check if a row in azure table storage contains specific value

Tags: azure, azure-logic-apps

**Requirement**

Create a logic app to read data from a table. If a row contains a particular value for a column "region", then that row must be inserted in to another table.

**Issue**

I am able to get all the entities from storage table using "Get Entities" action. I placed a for each to iterate through all entities. However, in "Condition" action, i am unable to check for particular column value for each record.

[image]

Comment: Hi Mahesh, may I know if your problem was solved ? If still have any other problem, please let me know.

Answer (score 3):

You can add a parameter("Select Query") under the "Get entities" action and type "region" in it.(please refer to the two screenshots below)

[image]

[image]

Then use the expression below to get the value of "region" column:

```
items('For_each')?['region']
```

[image]